# Microsoft Office Document Version Control

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, git, latex

I'm used to storing all of my documentation in TeX documents that live happily in Git and can be updated and committed at the same cadence as the code changes being documented.

Sadly, I work in an office with a lot of Git/TeX illiterate folks who still need to read and edit our documentation. They are exclusively comfortable with Microsoft Word and Excel. SharePoint offers mediocre version control, but managing documents through this tool is tedious and the conflict resolution is non-existent.

Has anyone come up with a satisfactory solution for storing word documents in git?

Not the first time this question has been asked, but the only answer I find is to use something like Pandoc to convert Word documents to plain text format and then store that in git. Even if Pandoc (or another converter) worked seamlessly (which they don't), This is still a rather technical process before and after and is still too complicated for our tech illiterates. I want to know if things have changed since 2015, if somebody has come out with a really robust library for doing proper directed-tree revision mapping on the Microsoft compressed xml format.